# como crear un carrusel de componentes con react

Tags: reactjs, carrusel, material-ui

estoy intentando realizar un carrucel horizontal con cartas, las cartas contienen informacion de usuario, lo que tengo creado simplemente es un contenedor con botones a la izquierda y a la derecha para poder moverme dentro de ella, pero tengo un problema, no se como implementar esa logica, no se por donde empezar, nunca lo hice, esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { IconButton, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'
import CardSugerencias from './cardSugerencia'
import ArrowBackIosRoundedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIosRounded';

const useStyles = makeStyles(()=>({
  root: {
    width: '34rem',
    overflowX: 'auto',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    position: 'relative',
    margin: '0 auto',
    overflowY: 'hidden',
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      display: 'none'
    },
    padding: '.5rem'
  },
  containerBtnLeft: {
    width: '2rem',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    opacity: 0,
    transition: 'all .5s',
    '&:hover': {
      opacity: 1
    }
  },
  containerBtnRight: {
    width: '2rem',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    opacity: 0,
    transition: 'all .5s',
    '&:hover': {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
}))

const Contenedor = () => {

  const left: () => void = () => {

  }

  const right: () => void = () => {

  }

  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.containerBtnLeft}>
        <IconButton onClick={left} size="small">
          <ArrowBackIosRoundedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.containerBtnRight}>
        <IconButton onClick={right} size="small">
          <ArrowBackIosRoundedIcon style={{transform: 'rotate(180deg)'}} />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
      {[...new Array(10)].map((item)=>(<CardSugerencias data={item} />))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Contenedor
```

como pueden ver, tengo los botones sin ninguna lógica por que la verdad no se como hacer, lo que yo intento hacer es mostrar los primeros ítems que aparezcan, al dar click en el botón de la derecha, que se muestren los otros ítems que no se veían, algo así como el contenedor de historias de instagram web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes un carrusel sencillo. Cuando hace clic en los botones, comprueba si es el primer elemento o el último elemento. Si es el primer elemento, establézcala como el último elemento, de lo contrario -1. Si es el último elemento, restablezca a 0, de lo contrario +1.

Para `transition`, comprueba el siguiente elemento y el elemento anterior y agrega la clase correcta.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { IconButton, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CardSugerencias } from "./CardSugerencias";
import ArrowBackIosRoundedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIosRounded";

const lista = [...new Array(10)];

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  btn: {
    zIndex: 1001,
    marginTop: "25%"
  },
  carrousel_wrapper: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  carrousel: {
    overflow: "hidden",
    width: "90%",
    margin: "auto"
  }
}));

const Contenedor = () => {
  const [elementoActivo, setElementoActivo] = useState(0);
  const [anterior, setAnterior] = useState(lista.length - 1);
  const [siguiente, setSiguiente] = useState(elementoActivo + 1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (elementoActivo === 0) {
      setAnterior(lista.length - 1);
      setSiguiente(elementoActivo + 1);
    } else if (elementoActivo === lista.length - 1) {
      setAnterior(elementoActivo - 1);
      setSiguiente(0);
    } else {
      setAnterior(elementoActivo - 1);
      setSiguiente(elementoActivo + 1);
    }
  }, [elementoActivo]);

  //mover elemento
  const moverImagenDerecha = () => {
    // Si es el último elemento, restablezca a 0, de lo contrario +1
    if (elementoActivo === lista.length - 1) {
      setElementoActivo(0);
    } else {
      setElementoActivo(elementoActivo + 1);
    }
  };

  //mover elemento
  const moverImagenIzquierda = () => {
    // Si es el primer elemento, establézcala como el último elemento, de lo contrario -1
    if (elementoActivo === 0) {
      setElementoActivo(lista.length - 1);
    } else {
      setElementoActivo(elementoActivo - 1);
    }
  };

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.carrousel_wrapper}>
      <div className={classes.btn}>
        <IconButton onClick={moverImagenIzquierda} size="small">
          <ArrowBackIosRoundedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.carrousel}>
        {lista.map((elemento, index) => (
          <CardSugerencias
            data={
              <div>
                <h2>{index}</h2>
                {[...new Array(10)].map((item, i) => (
                  <div>{i}</div>
                ))}
              </div>
            }
            activo={elementoActivo === index}
            anterior={anterior === index}
            siguiente={siguiente === index}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.btn}>
        <IconButton onClick={moverImagenDerecha} size="small">
          <ArrowBackIosRoundedIcon style={{ transform: "rotate(180deg)" }} />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contenedor;
```

CardSugerencia.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import classnames from "classnames";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  carrusel_elemento: {
    opacity: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 100
  },
  activo: {
    opacity: 1,
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: 900,
    width: "100%",
    margin: "auto",
    transition: "transform .5s, opacity .5s, z-index .5s"
  },
  anterior: {
    transform: "translateX(-100%)"
  },
  siguiente: {
    transform: "translateX(100%)"
  }
}));

export const CardSugerencias = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div
      className={classnames(
        props.activo ? classes.activo : classes.carrusel_elemento,
        props.anterior ? classes.anterior : "",
        props.siguiente ? classes.siguiente : ""
      )}
    >
      {props.data}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Demo en Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-rain-en609?file=/src/components/Carrusel.js:0-2622)

Comment: muy buen ejemplo, en mi app yo necesito mostrar datos y no una imagen, en tu ejemplo las imagenes se muestran completas, lo que yo necesito es mostrar varios items, max 6 o 7 dentro del carrusel, me explico ?

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu pregunta con el contenido que deseas mostrar en `<CardSugerencias />`?

Comment: no creo que haga falta, podrías simular los componentes con las mismas imágenes que agregaste, al fin y al cabo esta muy bien formulada tu respuesta, simplemente mostrar mas imágenes dentro del carrusel y no solo una que abarque todo

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta con números como datos.
Entonces puedes resolver tu problema?

Comment: has usado instagram web, mas presisamente las historias? si es asi, estoy tratando de crear algo como ese carrusel

Comment: Supongo que no quieres `transition` cuando dices como "instagram web". Si no quieres `transition`, solo quitas las clases `anterior`, `siguiente` y  este parte: `transition: "transform .5s, opacity .5s, z-index .5s"`. Y no necesitas el parte en `useEffect`. Todo es para el `transition` efecto.

Comment: creo que sigues sin entenderme

Comment: Es muy difícil ayudarte cuando no explicas en más detalle. Cuando dices Instagram web te refieres al css? Porque tu pregunta era cómo funcionan los botones y eso es lo que hice en el código.

Answer (score -6):

Lo bueno de React, y otros frameworks de front-end, es que no siempre necesitas tú hacer los componentes con la funcionalidad que necesitas; especialmente cuando las funcionalidades pueden llegar a ser muy complejas, puedes también utilizar componentes creados por otras personas en tu proyecto

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel

Encontré este carrusel rápido buscando en google, si no tienes problema utilizando este carrusel te recomiendo utilizarlo, y seguir utilizando componentes creados por la comunidad

Comment: Te recomiendo leas [answer], tu respuesta tiene problemas de formato pues es en escencia solo un enlace sin contar además que la pregunta tiene una recompensa abierta, te recomiendo hagas el [tour] y trates de mejorar el contenido de la misma

Comment: igualmente, no es lo que estoy buscando